# Appending echo'ed elements with js

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php code echoes 4 different elements (time, h2, p and a) and i want to put time and h2 elements into a div tag with class="post-header".

sample php code

```
    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<time id='time1' class='postdate'>".$row["date"]."</time>";
            echo "<h2 id='title1' class='post-title'>".$row["title"]."</h2>";
            echo "<p class='post-text'>".$row["p"]."</p>";
            echo "<a class='source' href='".$row["source"]."'>Source</a>";
        }
```

what i tried so far with js is appendChild, append and innerHTML but couldn't make it work. I prefer not to ping server again. Any tips?

Comment: if that is the case, would it be a fine solution to do:  echo "<div class ='post-header'><time id='time1' class='postdate'>".$row["date"]."</time></div>"; echo "<div class='post-header'><h2 id='title1' class='post-title'>".$row["title"]."</h2></div>"; ..... etc?

Comment: Yeah it worked. Thanks a lot dude, i can sleep now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method:

```
$data="";
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data="<time id='time1' class='postdate'>".$row['date']."</time>"
            ."<h2 id='title1' class='post-title'>".$row['title']."</h2>".
             "<p class='post-text'>".$row['p']."</p>".
             "<a class='source' href='".$row['source']."'>Source</a>";
        }

             echo $data;
```